# Integrating jasmine plugins into protractor and lineman

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

How does one integrate a jasmine plugin (such as jasmine-jquery) in an e2e protractor test in a Lineman project?

Comment: Why do you want jasmine-jquery? I'm afraid it won't do you much good - Protractor tests only have access to the browser through the WebDriver wire protocol and WebElements, which are not the same as jQuery elements.

Comment: It's helpful when trying to speed up a test by using getInnerHtml and parsing it locally instead of waiting for a multiple getText() calls to resolve.